# Perl - map-each-function_returning_hash - command does not work as one liner

Tags: perl

I have function which return hash of arrays:

```
print Dumper { &is_needle_in_haystack( \@model_groups_names, \%groups_by_name_HoA ) };

$VAR1 = {    # Condensed
    'ng_a2' => [ 'ng_a2', '*', 143, ],
    'ng_b3' => [ 'ng_b3', '*', 144, '' ],
    'ng_g1' => [ 'ng_g1', '*', 158, ],
    'ng_a1' => [ 'ng_a1', '*', 143, ],
    'ng_d2' => [ 'ng_d2', '*', 155, '' ]
};
```

From this output I need numbers that are on `[2]` arrays index. I have tried this:

```
print Dumper map {$_->[2]} values &is_needle_in_haystack(\@model_groups_names, \%groups_by_name_HoA)
```

Also tried this partial solution but also does not return any result:

```
print Dumper values &is_needle_in_haystack(\@model_groups_names, \%groups_by_name_HoA);
```

I have to broke it down to smaller pieces to get desired output:

```
my %HoA = &is_needle_in_haystack(\@model_groups_names, \%groups_by_name_HoA);
my @A = values %HoA;
my @gid = map {$_->[2]} @A;

print Dumper @gid

$VAR1 = 143;
$VAR2 = 144;
$VAR3 = 158;
$VAR4 = 143;
$VAR5 = 155;
```

What I am doing wrong? Do I need some parenthesis or what is the clue?

Comment: You should know that if you store the return values from the subroutine in a hash, you may overwrite duplicate keys. This is not an issue if this is supposed to be a hash. You might find that returning a hash reference is preferable to returning a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `is_needle_in_haystack()` function returns list and you can call `values` only on hash variables. One of the solutions is to make a hash reference, and immediately dereference it `%{{ <list> }}`

```
my @gid = map { $_->[2] } values %{{ is_needle_in_haystack(\@model_groups_names, \%groups_by_name_HoA) }};
```

Still, this is my personal favorite,

```
my %HoA = is_needle_in_haystack(\@model_groups_names, \%groups_by_name_HoA);
my @gid = map { $_->[2] } values %HoA;
```

Comment: How is possible that is_needle_in_haystack() is returning list instead of hash? When you check first Data::Dumper output it shows hash not a list or am I wrong? Also the last line in is_needle_in_haystack() ends with:  %return_h

Comment: @WakanTanka note that you've used `{}` braces which are effectively making hashref.

Comment: This is output from debugger: DB<5> print ref \%return_h
HASH

Comment: Yes I see that with wrapping variable with {} or [] I can get another type but as I said I am returning %return_h which is before constructed as $return_h{$haystack_key} = $haystack_value;

Comment: @WakanTanka when you backslash hash as you did in debugger, it makes reference to the variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61350/discussion-between-wakan-tanka-and-mpapec).

Answer (score 2):

> I have function which return hash of arrays:

Your sub does not return a hash of arrays. The hash you see in the `Dumper` output is constructed outside of your sub by `{ }`. Your sub returns a list of scalars consisting of pairs of strings and array references.

> How is possible that `is_needle_in_haystack()` is returning list instead of hash?

Well, for starters, it's impossible for subs to return hashes. The only think a sub can return is a list of scalars. (In scalar context, that list must be exactly one scalar long.)

If you had a returned a reference to a hash, you could have done

```
map { $_->[2] } values %{ is_needle_in_haystack() }
```

But you didn't, so you need to create the hash as you did for `Dumper`.

```
map { $_->[2] } values %{ { is_needle_in_haystack() } }
```

Actually, you don't. You can extract what you want from the returned list without making
a hash first.

```
my $i;  map { $_->[2] } grep { ++$i % 2 } is_needle_in_haystack()
```

or

```
map { $_->[2] } grep { ref($_) } is_needle_in_haystack()
```